# Bruteforcing hardware-encrypted SSD

Tags: encryption, brute-force, hardware

Can you bruteforce a hardware-encrypted SSD drive? I mean recovering the password needed to unlock the drive. 
Is there any software could do this? Here the focus is the software that could do the job.

Comment: From my understanding, anything encrypted can be bruteforced. The only problem is finding the key (and have the time to find it).

Comment: The whole point about bruteforcing is that you don't "recover" the password, you try all of the possible combinations and see if it works. There is software that allows you to do it(it's a very simple concept so you could probably easily implement it yourself), but if the password is well-chosen, it may take ages.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security. Are you asking about in-built brute-force protections, like device/key wiping after a few failures?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can brute-force a hardware-encrypted SSD drive.

The time it takes to be successful though is up to the method used, the length of the password and the hardware & software capabilities of the machine doing the BF attack (which dictates how many tries/sec can be attempted).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend disassembling the drive's firmware and taking a closer look at the crypto inside. With this kind of proprietary crypto it's [often flawed](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) and you may find bugs that will make your attack much easier, as pure bruteforce on correctly implemented AES is infeasible.